# How to import data into SQLite DB table from Excel file using C++ Qt creater?

Tags: c++, excel, database, sqlite, qt

How to import data from an .xlsx file, and insert it into a table in an sqlite database, using Qt created with C++.

Comment: it would be good if you indicate that you have tried, an excel is very generic, does it have a special format? see https://wiki.qt.io/Handling_Microsoft_Excel_file_format

Comment: signs? Its a noraml typr XL sheet with data . I will check this link . thank you

Comment: If you can, I suggest to convert the file to csv format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 QSqlDatabase db_SQLite = 
  QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE","sqlite_connection");
  db.setDatabaseName("Db"); 
  QSqlDatabase db_XL = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC", "xlsx_connection");
    db_XL.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" + QString("D:/Sample_Data.xlsx"));
    if(db_XL.open())
    {

     QSqlQuery *query = new QSqlQuery(db_XL);
     query->exec("select * from [" + QString("Sheet1") + "$]");
     while (query->next())
     {

         QSqlDatabase db_SQLite = QSqlDatabase::database("sqlite_connection");
          if(db_SQLite.open())
          {


              QSqlQuery * querytoDb = new QSqlQuery(db_SQLite);
              querytoDb->exec("CREATE TABLE TableName ("
                                "DataOne INTEGER,"
                                "Data2 TEXT,"
                                "Data3 REAL);")

              querytoDb->prepare("INSERT INTO TableName(DataOne, Data2, Data3,) values(:one, :two, :three)");
              querytoDb->bindValue(":one",query->value(0).toInt());
              querytoDb->bindValue(":two",query->value(0).toDateTime());
              querytoDb->bindValue(":three",query->value(0).toDouble());


              qDebug()<<querytoDb->exec()<<endl;
          }
     }
    db_XL.close();
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("xlsx_connection");
    }
```